# Number precision too large?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Trying to run a pl/sql function I'm getting the following error:

> An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an   attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable declared NUMBER(2).

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_service_yrs
  (p_empid IN employees.employee_id%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_yrsjh NUMBER(3,2);
  v_yrsemp NUMBER(3, 2);
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(TRUNC(((end_date-start_date)/365),2))
  INTO v_yrsjh
  FROM job_history
  WHERE employee_id=p_empid;

  IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    v_yrsjh:=0;
  END IF;

  SELECT TRUNC(((sysdate-hire_date)/365), 2)+v_yrsjh
  INTO v_yrsemp
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id=p_empid;

  IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20202, 'Wrong employee id');
  END IF;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_yrsjh);
  RETURN v_yrsemp;
END get_service_yrs;
```

It says that the error it is the line 15. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error is at `NUMBER(3,2)`

I suppose you want to work with number of days but you try to fit it in a `NUMBER(3,2)` datatype and an error is raised when the number of days is greater than 999.

try: `NUMBER(7)` for `v_yrsjh` and for `v_yrsemp`